# Advice on playing 16 HTML5 videos simultaneously, obvious lag issues

Tags: jquery, html, video

so if you point your webkit browser here:
http://graysonearle.com/bluemen/

and hit PlayAll on the side, I'm curious what your results are. For me, it works 90% of the time, but often videos won't play to the end (the solid color). I'm wondering if there's a shot in hell that this will work or if I should explore other options. Even gifs seem to lag at times. Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: no chance in hell :-) Can you composite them into one larger video?

Comment: Well the idea is to give the user the ability to change which videos are where on the fly. I can figure how to composite videos live offline, but is there a library fast enough for that in an online environment?